# Remove Anaconda3 / set Python Path

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I uninstall anaconda and would like use python3.6... 
If I write **pip list** in terminal, I became this Error:

```
bash: /home/XXX/.local/bin/pip: /home/XXX/anaconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I would like uninstall anaconda complete from my Ubuntu 16.04 and use only python3.6

What I do wrong??

Comment: In order to uninstall anaconda, just delete the entire folder in which anaconda is present. Eg: sudo rm -rf ~/username/software/anaconda3

Comment: Yes I do this! But than my pip is not work.. I became the error: Bad intepreter

Comment: Check your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` (in your home dir). Are there any traces of Anaconda left? I.e. is there something like `export PATH="/Users/XXX/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`? If so: remove it.